# One-way encryption methods

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

This is a just a theoretical question.  I'm at a point of starting to program a huge multi-server/multi-client network view.

**Question:**
What are the possible methods of *Irreversible Encryption* or aka *One-Way Encryption*?  And what are the most suitable to be implemented in my case and in .NET?

Can anyone supply me with just a list of method names!

Comment: md5 or sha256?  Is there really anything else to say?

Comment: If encryption were irreversible, what would be the point?  (Making the distinction between hashing algorithms...)

Comment: Just need a list not a comparison !!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
byte[] data = new byte[DATA_SIZE];
byte[] result;
SHA256 shaM = new SHA256Managed();
result = shaM.ComputeHash(data);
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92f9ye3s.aspx) is the overview and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) is the namespace with standard features. Simply look at [HashAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.aspx) and its descendants.

Comment: Just 8 Minutes ,,, :D You are my Answer . Anyway Thanks

Comment: Yeah I was just waiting 10 minutes to apply your answer as perfect :D

Answer (score 8):

You basically want to either use MD5 or SHA-256. Oh, and FYI, if it's one way, it's called a *hash*. The MSDN documentation covers both hashes extensively.

Answer (score 3):

As have been mentioned by others, md5 and sha are hashing algorithms that can be used for this. One thing that have to be taken into account before you pick one though, is how important is it that it gets "decrypted" (hashes can't be decrypted in the normal sense of the word). MD5 and SHA are designed to be fast, which means that creating rainbow tables ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_tables ) with a lot of hashes will be fast too. With the speed of modern GPUs hundreds of millions of hashes can be generated every second, which means it is possible to brute force MD5 and SHA fairly quickly.

If you are storing things like password it is better to use a hashing algorithm that is designed to be slow, like bcrypt ( http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/ )

Answer (score 1):

For any new visitors to this question, [crackstation.net](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) has a full .NET implementation [at the bottom](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode), along with a rather detailed explanation of what you should do and how it all works

The following code is copied without modifications from crackstation.net

```
/* 
 * Password Hashing With PBKDF2 (http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).
 * Copyright (c) 2013, Taylor Hornby
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, 
 * this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 * this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation 
 * and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE 
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE 
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR 
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF 
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS 
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN 
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) 
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE 
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace PasswordHash
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Salted password hashing with PBKDF2-SHA1.
    /// Author: havoc AT defuse.ca
    /// www: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm
    /// Compatibility: .NET 3.0 and later.
    /// </summary>
    public class PasswordHash
    {
        // The following constants may be changed without breaking existing hashes.
        public const int SALT_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
        public const int HASH_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
        public const int PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 1000;

        public const int ITERATION_INDEX = 0;
        public const int SALT_INDEX = 1;
        public const int PBKDF2_INDEX = 2;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a salted PBKDF2 hash of the password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password">The password to hash.</param>
        /// <returns>The hash of the password.</returns>
        public static string CreateHash(string password)
        {
            // Generate a random salt
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_BYTE_SIZE];
            csprng.GetBytes(salt);

            // Hash the password and encode the parameters
            byte[] hash = PBKDF2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE);
            return PBKDF2_ITERATIONS + ":" +
                Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + ":" +
                Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validates a password given a hash of the correct one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password">The password to check.</param>
        /// <param name="correctHash">A hash of the correct password.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the password is correct. False otherwise.</returns>
        public static bool ValidatePassword(string password, string correctHash)
        {
            // Extract the parameters from the hash
            char[] delimiter = { ':' };
            string[] split = correctHash.Split(delimiter);
            int iterations = Int32.Parse(split[ITERATION_INDEX]);
            byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String(split[SALT_INDEX]);
            byte[] hash = Convert.FromBase64String(split[PBKDF2_INDEX]);

            byte[] testHash = PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, hash.Length);
            return SlowEquals(hash, testHash);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares two byte arrays in length-constant time. This comparison
        /// method is used so that password hashes cannot be extracted from
        /// on-line systems using a timing attack and then attacked off-line.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">The first byte array.</param>
        /// <param name="b">The second byte array.</param>
        /// <returns>True if both byte arrays are equal. False otherwise.</returns>
        private static bool SlowEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b)
        {
            uint diff = (uint)a.Length ^ (uint)b.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length && i < b.Length; i++)
                diff |= (uint)(a[i] ^ b[i]);
            return diff == 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Computes the PBKDF2-SHA1 hash of a password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password">The password to hash.</param>
        /// <param name="salt">The salt.</param>
        /// <param name="iterations">The PBKDF2 iteration count.</param>
        /// <param name="outputBytes">The length of the hash to generate, in bytes.</param>
        /// <returns>A hash of the password.</returns>
        private static byte[] PBKDF2(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputBytes)
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
            pbkdf2.IterationCount = iterations;
            return pbkdf2.GetBytes(outputBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

A few things of note:

- The original post and [OWASP guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_Keyed_functions) both suggest strengthening the encryption using HMAC
- Iteration count in the above implementation is probably a little low. [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Work_Factor) and [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3993) suggest a self balancing work load
- Salt size in the implementation above is set to 24 but if i'm reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23169788/289992) correctly it should not go above 20. That said, I'm anything but an expert in cryptography so I can't really say whether that claim is true or false

Comment: Why is it necessary to use a constant-time compare when comparing hashes which are essentially arrays of random bytes?